# SSH Bind Address - Cannot Assign Requested Address

Tags: ssh

I've got 2 NIC's, and just want to SSH from one specific interface.  As you can see, the -b option in ssh doesn't seem to be able to use my address.  Not sure why?

```
$ ip a show enp8s0 | grep "default\|inet "
2: enp8s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,PROMISC,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast master INT-VRF1 state UP group default qlen 1000
    inet 172.31.16.22/24 brd 172.31.16.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute enp8s0

$ ping -I enp8s0 172.31.16.10
PING 172.31.16.10 (172.31.16.10) from 172.31.16.22 enp8s0: 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 172.31.16.10: icmp_seq=1 ttl=255 time=0.627 ms
64 bytes from 172.31.16.10: icmp_seq=2 ttl=255 time=2.49 ms

$ ssh -b 172.31.16.22 172.31.16.10
bind 172.31.16.22: Cannot assign requested address
ssh: connect to host 172.31.16.10 port 22: failure
```

It's like SSH is unaware of the VRF.  I thought this could be a namespace issue so tried also using the kernel settings below to no avail.

```
$ sudo sysctl -a | grep l3mdev
net.ipv4.raw_l3mdev_accept = 1
net.ipv4.tcp_l3mdev_accept = 1
net.ipv4.udp_l3mdev_accept = 1
```

Added below as per request of comment:

```
$ ip -4 addr list | grep 172.31.16.22
inet 172.31.16.22/24 brd 172.31.16.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute enp8s0
```

#### UPDATE

I did manage to get this working via the below:

```
$ sudo ip vrf exec INT-VRF1 ssh 172.31.16.10
```

However, I can only get it working with sudo.  Otherwise I get:

```
$ ip vrf exec INT-VRF1 ssh 172.31.16.10
Failed to load BPF prog: 'Operation not permitted'
```

Not sure why really.  But I just need to be able to use client apps  like SSH over this interface.  How/What is the way to do it?

The only thing I can seem to find online is about binding the application's SO_BINDTODEVICE to a certain interface in order to force a socket to be created on a specific NIC.  But I'm really not sure how to go about setting this up with for an SSH client connection.

Comment: Show the output of `ip -4 addr list`.  If the IP doesnt show bound to these systems in the address lists you cant bind to the IP with services on system.

Comment: Updated post to show its there